# Rails is not starting after brew upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zsh

This started to happen after i upgraded brew packages.

```
% rails s
zsh: abort      rails s
```

I have no idea what's going on here because there are no other error messages. Seems like some brew package fails at some point which leads to exit, but i can't understand how can I find this package.

How can i fix or debug this?

Comment: What version of Rails are you trying to run? Depending on what all you updated, Rails can hang due to missing/changed files.

Comment: @CannonMoyer Rails 5.2.4.2, ruby 2.6.5p114

Comment: Try starting your console `rails console`. See if there are any errors. Do you have any tests you can run? Also try `rails s -b 0.0.0.0` instead of `rails s`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem was to recompile gemset

```
rvm gemset pristine
```